# graphql duplicated documents error when retreiving multiple data types in Gatsby-node.js

Tags: graphql, gatsby, kentico, kentico-kontent

I have a simple Gatsby prototype that utilizes [Kentico Cloud](https://kenticocloud.com/) as a data source. Luckily for me, they have already built a [source plugin](https://github.com/Kentico/gatsby-source-kentico-cloud) that I'm utilizing to fetch a single data type called 'BlogPost'. This works as expected.

**gatsby-node.js source**

```
const path = require(`path`);

exports.createPages = ({graphql, actions}) => {
    const { createPage } = actions;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        graphql(`
        {
            allKenticoCloudItemBlogPost {
              edges {
                node {
                  elements {
                    url_slug{
                      value
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        `).then(result => {        
            console.log(result);
            result.data.allKenticoCloudItemBlogPost.edges.map(({node}) => {
                createPage({
                    path: `${node.elements.url_slug.value}`,
                    component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/blog-post.js`),
                    context: {
                        slug: node.elements.url_slug.value,
                    },
                })
            })
            resolve();
        })
    });

}
```

This works great, but I really want to add a second data type called 'Articles'

Following the [Gatsby Kentico Starter Template Example](https://github.com/Kentico/gatsby-starter-kentico-cloud), I've modified my gatsby-node.js file

```
const path = require(`path`);

exports.createPages = ({graphql, actions}) => {
    const { createPage } = actions;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        graphql(`
        {
          allKenticoCloudItemBlogPost {
            edges {
              node {
                elements {
                  url_slug{
                    value
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
          allKenticoCloudItemArticle{
            edges{
              node{
                elements{
                  url_slug{
                    value
                  } 
                }
                internal{
                  type
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        `).then(result => {
            console.log('START HERE');        
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
            result.data.allKenticoCloudItemBlogPost.edges.map(({node}) => {
              createPage({
                  path: `${node.elements.url_slug.value}`,
                  component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/blog-post.js`),
                  context: {
                      slug: node.elements.url_slug.value,
                  },
              })
            });
            result.data.allKenticoCloudItemArticle.edges.map(({node}) => {
              createPage({
                path: `${node.elements.url_slug.value}`,
                component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/article.js`),
                context: {
                  slug: node.elements.url_slug.value,
                },
              })
            })
            resolve();
        })
    });
}
```

As you can see, I logged the results so I could see what they look like.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Produces

```
{
  "data": {
    "allKenticoCloudItemBlogPost": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": { "elements": { "url_slug": { "value": "my-first-post" } } }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "elements": { "url_slug": { "value": "my-second-blog-post" } }
          }
        },
        { "node": { "elements": { "url_slug": { "value": "3rd-blog-post" } } } }
      ]
    },
    "allKenticoCloudItemArticle": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "elements": { "url_slug": { "value": "article-1-example" } },
            "internal": { "type": "KenticoCloudItemArticle" }
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "elements": { "url_slug": { "value": "article-2" } },
            "internal": { "type": "KenticoCloudItemArticle" }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

So far, so good. I see what I expect to see.

And when I run `gatsby develop` it actually compiles successfully, but with a graphQL Error

> error GraphQL Error There was an error while compiling your site's
>   GraphQL queries.   Error: RelayParser: Encountered duplicate
>   defintitions for one or more documents: each document must have a
>   unique name. Duplicated documents:
>   - templateBuilder

I attempted to solve this by putting a comma after my first BlogPost query.

```
graphql(`
{
  allKenticoCloudItemBlogPost {
    edges {
      node {
        elements {
          url_slug{
            value
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  allKenticoCloudItemArticle{
    edges{
      node{
        elements{
          url_slug{
            value
          } 
        }
        internal{
          type
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I attempted to put a new query in as a new promise but got a notification from my editor that it was unreachable code so I know that won't work.

It has to be something small as I've modeled my code after the [Gatsby Kentico Source Plugin starter](https://github.com/Kentico/gatsby-starter-kentico-cloud) which uses the same technologies I am. I can download and run that project with no problem. So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

**EDIT**

I solved this. The problem was in templates for each data type. I was naming both queries as templateBuilder. I changed the blog template to blogBuilder and the article template to articleBuilder. Works like a charm now.

**article.js**

```
export const query = graphql`
  query articleBuilder($slug: String!) {
    kenticoCloudItemArticle(elements: { url_slug: { value: { eq: $slug } } }) {
      elements {
        article_title {
          value
        }
        article_content {
          value
        }
        article_date {
          value
        }
        url_slug {
          value
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

**blog-post.js**

```
export const query = graphql`
  query blogBuilder($slug: String!) {
    kenticoCloudItemBlogPost(elements: { url_slug: { value: { eq: $slug } } }) {
      elements {
        blog_title {
          value
        }
        blog_content {
          value
        }
        blog_date {
          value
        }
        url_slug {
          value
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Comment: Do you have the source code somewhere to be able to try it locally?

Comment: I literally just solved it. The problem were the queries on the template pages. They were named the same thing. See my edit above.

Answer (score 5):

The problem was in templates for each data type. I was naming both queries as templateBuilder. I changed the blog template to blogBuilder and the article template to articleBuilder.

See above edit for more details and code examples.